# Issues in elasticsearch server running in docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, docker-compose

I am new to Docker. I have developed a webapp that needs elasticsearch server up and running, and the server itself listens for any user request. IN our workflow, we would like to see elasticsearch up and running, then logstash to be able to publish data (by reading the data we have with the help of logstash conf files), and finally launch the webapp we have. I am advised to use docker compose as it helps to compose multiple servers.
SO, we have three sub-directories, one for each es, logstash and webapp.

In my first step, I have in my elasticsearch dockerfile the below lines

```
FROM elasticsearch:latest

RUN plugin -i elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

Similarly, I have Dockerfile in other sub-directories as well. 
I use the command 'docker-compose up' to start the process. Once, ES is built ad logstash will be built. When logstash is being built, it tries to publish data to ES. But it finds here that ES is not up and running.I see connection refused exception. Can someone tell why this error comes? The contents in the Dockerfile is ok?

I think, I am not using docker / docker-compose the way I should use. May be, couple of pointers to learning materials will be helpful. I find plenty but could not relate to the use case I have.

Answer (score 0):

There are two phases when running `up`. The "build" phase, which runs `docker build`, and the "run" phase, which runs the equivalent of `docker run`.  During the build phase there is no support for linking to other containers, so you won't be able to connect to them.

An easy solution is to run part of the setup during the "run" phase, but the downside is that it isn't cached and has to be performed each time.

To include it as part of the build phase, you can export the json that needs to be sent to ES, include it as part of the ES build, and then have a step that does something like this:

1. start es
2. wait for es to be available
3. run curl to PUT/POST the data to ES
4. stop es